How do I fix the checkbox and label issue?
enter image description here
Trying to align checkbox and text next to each other but I can't seem to fix the issue no matter what I try.
I have been working on this for hours researching and trying different codes I came across online. There has to be an issue that I am not seeing. I visited at least 5-10 websites on checkbox and label alignment. Since those didn't work then there must be something else that is preventing the alignment. The only time I got them together was inline-flex but the text words were squashed together and couldn't move them nor fix the text.

Emm. It what you need is align-self?

Welcome to StackOverflow!  It's hard to know without a code example (please feel free to edit your post to include your code, helps a lot in writing answers) but it sounds like if your words are being squished, the width available to your label may not be wide enough to fit the words in.  Providing a code example would help a lot in understanding your problem.
